# SVN - Structure Repository for vendor and own code to be seperate

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need to find a way to structure a repository so that i have the following:

```
Trunk
  This is live 

Branches
  Vendor
     Vendor framework v1
     Vender framework v1 etc etc
  Company
      The is where my code lives

  Development
      A
      B
      C
```

The project relies on the company files and the vendor files being merged together to form the project but I want to keep them separate in the repository.  So for example, I would check out the company branch and work with it.  Commit my changes.  Then this is where I get stuck.  How do i get those changes in to a development branch (each of which should be a merged version of Company and Vendor) for testing and then finally pushing that development branch to live.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather structure it this way:

```
trunk
    Vendor
        Framworks 1
    Company
        company code
branches
    Live (copy/merge of trunk)
        Vendor (this gets automatically pulled in by the copy/merge from trunk to live)
        Company (same here)
    Development
        A (copy of trunk)
            Vendor
            Company
        B (copy of trunk)
            (same here)
tags
    Version 1.0 (copy of live)
        ....
    Version 2.0 (copy of live)
    .....
```

This way the most current branch is trunk. This is your working-area.

If you want to make some bigger changes (or want to have each change reviewed/tested seperately) branch it into a development branch, make your changes, and merge back into trunk. After each back-merge you are free to keep the development branches or delete them.

If all testing is ok and you want to put it live, merge trunk into the Live-branch.

A common concept is also to version each release version with a tag. In this case you just copy live into a tag-branch and give it a version name.

You will notice that each branch (live, development a, development b, version 1, version 2) will also contain all vendor-frameworks and all your code, but this is ok because those copies cost only a few bytes in the subversion-repository.

Comment: That seems odd to me to have the development branch in trunk - is this a common structure?

Comment: How would you merge the vendor framework and company code into 1 structure ready for the live branch?

Comment: Yes, this is a common structure. For example boost, llvm and subversion itself organize their repositories like this. This way you don't have to do different merges. Each development branch and the live branch contain all code that is needed for your application.

Comment: Tobias - Thanks for the help so far.  How do i get the two structures: Vendor & Company merged into one structure and pushed to live?

Comment: Example: You have libA.1.0 and libB.1.2 and your code. You make changes to your code and deploy it into branches/live. At some point you want to update libA. You make this update inside trunk. Now you merge all changes (including all updated libs) from trunk into branches/live. This also works perfectly with svn-externals (of which I haven't talked about yet).

Comment: I should also note that the most important point is that only on the live version whether it be trunk or a branch - the live has to be a merged structure of the vendor and company structures i.e. they need to merge to become one heirarchy of files.  Outside of live they need to be sperate